# Django: QueryDict issue with jQuery

Tags: jquery, python, django

Relatively new to django (but impressed).
Actual problem: I am trying to connect the [Dropbox Chooser](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser) with `Django` (via `jQuery`).

#### Code on the client side:

```
var data = {'files': files, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{% url 'youtube:save_dropbox_files' %}",
    data: data
});
```

Nothing special here, `files` is an array of the selected files from `Dropbox` (of the form `files[0][name] = 'Some name';` and `files[0][link] = 'Some link';`).

#### Code on the server side (Django view):

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def save_dropbox_files(request):
    files = request.POST.getlist('files')
    print files
    return render(request, 'youtube/ajax.html')
```

#### Question:

The `files` array on the Django side is always an empty list (`[]`).
Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def save_dropbox_files(request):
    files = request.POST.getlist('files[]')
    print files
    return render(request, 'youtube/ajax.html')
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is still empty.

Comment: Well, that's the syntax how you retreive a data array from Django sent by an Ajax response. Anyway, from the docs, if the key doesnt exist it will return an empty list, can you iter through all your POST/GET values and make sure its hitting the view? also can you send a test variable like hello: "world" and catch it in the view?